# Is there a one-to-many relationship between service & sku

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, google-cloud-billing

We have exported our GCP billing information to bigquery. When querying over it I've noticed that there seems to be a one-to-many relationship between service and sku. In other words, every instance of a sku seems to have the same service.

If this is indeed the case I can build some nice drill-down type reports whereby the report user drill from service to sku. before I build such a report though I want to confirm that this is indeed the case.

Can multiple instances of a SKU map to different services?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems the answer is "no, there isn't a one-to-many relationship between service and sku"

[image]

[image]

That's a shame.